# iOS how to simulate two taps on uitextview programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to Do this, Because I want to grab the selected text after tapping once. If there is another approach to select text, please let me know.

Thank you.

---

I modified Luiz solution, but it copies whole text on textview. What I want to achieve is to select one word.

```
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        textview.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, textview.text.length);
        NSString *selected = [self.textview.text substringWithRange:textview.selectedRange];
        NSLog (@"selected = %@", selected);

    }
```

---

EDIT:

I am still working to find a well-working code for this task.
In big apps like Kindle.app and Wakaru.app, it is possible to tap once and force selecting one word like two taps would do. Do you know how to do this or an idea to achieve this function?

Answer (score 2):

Try following these steps:

1. Set an IBOutlet to your UITextView, called, let's say, `myTextView`.
2. On `viewDidLoad` of your view controller, create an `UITapGestureRecognizer` for `myTextView`:

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTextView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
   [myTextView addGestureRecognizer:tapTextView];
   [tapTextView release];
   ```
3. Implement the `tap` method so it makes the UITextView selects its text:

   ```
    - (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    {
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
            myTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, myTextView.text.length);
        }
    }
   ```

I hope this helps!

Best regards!

Comment: I replaced myTextField with textview which is of class UITextView, this works, but not what I want to achieve. There are a lot of words on textview. I want to force textview to select a word when user tap once, like it would after tapping twice.

Comment: Not the whole text, just a specific word inside of it?

Comment: yes right. one tap in the middle of a word on textview, and then force selecting this word.

Comment: You could use the `locationInView` method from the recognizer to get a CGPoint from where inside the UITextView the tap took place. Then, if you set the UITextView to use a fixed width font you could have an estimate idea, based on the width and height of a single character, of the character position right below the tap. Then you would have to loop through the text to find the apropriate NSRange of the word containing that character.

Comment: That is a bit complicated, but thumb up for a good idea. Is it really impossible to force two taps to simulate "select" or "highlight" automatically programmatically?

Comment: how about simulating two taps programmatically? This way is simpler, dont you think? But I don't know how...

Comment: On simulating touches, I found this: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html However, as the author is warning, the use of that API is prohibited by Apple, so an app using it may be rejected.

Comment: I didnt read whole code, but I think it is not what I want. In big apps like Kindle.app and Wakaru, it is possible to tap once and force selecting one word.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is unclear.

When you say "If there is another approach to select text, please let me know", it seems that you just need to set the selectedRange property of the UITextView.

On the other hand, I don't see the link with double tapping....

Tim

Comment: when you click twice on a text on uitextview, a certain text will be selected, right? This function does I need to do programmatically without physically tapping twice. I know how to use selectedRange, but it happens nothing if no text has been selected, right? Is it more clear now?

Comment: Ok, do you know how to highlight text in uitextview?

Comment: To highlight text, just set the selectedRange property to the range of text to select.

Answer (score 1):

Having read all your comments, I think that I now understand your question to be:  "In a UITextView how can I have one tap select text in a the same way that a double tap would normally?"

I don't think you'll find a solution to this other than writing your own text view by hand.

Comment: you mentioned something about setSelectedRange, I searched on internet about it, but I could not find any useful information on how to implement it correctly.