# How to simulate Double Tap on UITextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, tap

When i write some thing in UITextfield and Double Tap on it ,It shows "Select"  ,"Select ALL" ,"Paste" option on ios device.I want to display same message via programming.

Can any one suggest the way to do it?

The Double Tap not get fire with with below code.

```
+(void)performanualTouch:(UITouch*)touch {
 UIEvent *eventDown = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];


    for (UIGestureRecognizer* gr in touch.view.gestureRecognizers) {       

        if ([gr isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            [gr touchesBegan:[eventDown allTouches] withEvent:eventDown];
            [touch setThePhase:UITouchPhaseEnded];
            UIEvent *eventUp = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch]; 
            [gr touchesEnded:[eventUp allTouches] withEvent:eventUp];
            [eventUp release];


            if (gr.cancelsTouchesInView) {

                return;
            }

        }
    }


 [touch.view touchesBegan:[eventDown allTouches] withEvent:eventDown];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:eventDown];
 [touch setThePhase:UITouchPhaseEnded];
 UIEvent *eventUp = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];
 [touch.view touchesEnded:[eventUp allTouches] withEvent:eventUp];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:eventUp];

 [eventDown release];
 [eventUp release];

}
```

Thanks

Comment: This should help you enough [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277535/ios-how-to-simulate-two-taps-on-uitextview-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation covering this particular need [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html)

The relevant part :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];

if ([theTouch tapCount] == 2  && [self becomeFirstResponder]) {

    // selection management code goes here...

    // bring up edit menu.
    UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake (currentSelection.x, currentSelection.y, SIDE, SIDE);
    [theMenu setTargetRect:selectionRect inView:self];
    [theMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

}
}
```